# How to pronounce "little" "button" "cotton" etc

Tags: pronunciation

Is it [lɪtl], [lɪdl] or [lɪ?l]? I think this question applies to some words with double t in them such as "rotten" "cotton" "button". (Standard American English pronunciation)

Comment: Who are you asking?  An English speaker from New York?  From London?  From Dublin?  From Sydney?  From Dallas?  Each might pronounce these words differently.

Comment: I cant specify, the most prevalent american english form that non natives are taught.

Comment: Standard American English pronounces the "t" sound, and (if good diction) even enunciates it a bit.  "Lit-tle". "Cot-ton". "But-ton."

Comment: Many good online dictionaries these days provide a "standard" pronunciation in both BrE and NAmE. They are reliable. Believe them.

Comment: I've explained it in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266963/106592). This question should be closed as a duplicate of that question so future visitors can find the answers easily. /////////// Briefly, the L in 'little' is syllabic and the T is released laterally.

Comment: For me (Chicago/Great Lakes region): Button and Cotton have glottal stops for the "t" sounds -- there is no "t" as in "tin" when I say these two words.  Little sounds like "liddle" where the d's are flaps followed by syllabic L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Button" and "cotton" are, to the best of my knowledge, always pronounced with a soft "t".

"Little" is usually pronounced the same: "lit' ul", Some people pronounce it with a hard "d": "lid' ul".